# Is Hadoop suitable for real-time querying, high data integrity application?

Tags: database, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I developed industrial software to poll data from devices/RTUs and log these data into relational database every seconds. The HMI of this software allows user to query these data from the database and represent it in the form of table/chart.

Now, this data stored can scale very fast. Normally, there can be easily 100 devices, in which each devices have 100 data, and need to be logged every seconds. We are talking about 100*100*60*60*24 = 864000000 data per day. This industrial software is expected to run 24/7, all year long.

Here's the problem, because of the scale of the data. The querying of the data can be painfully slow. If I were to plot data for 3 months, the SQL query would takes minutes.

My question is, does Hadoop (distributed storage and analytic system) is suitable for my application? Can I leverage the power of Hadoop to speed up the querying of data in my application? How?

Note that the data integrity in my application is very critical.

Comment: Please describe your problem more concrete. What database do you use? What kind of data do you load into? What requests do you want to do?

Comment: Understood, your data gets big but what do you do with that data afterwords? do you run any type of analytics on it?

Comment: @JackDaniel's I need to query data from my application afterwards. These querying is done based on user interaction with the HMI. The query is run on-the go.

Comment: @maxteneff I use relational database (PostgreSQL), the data I load into is numbers. the request I want to do is retreiving all the data of device A from time A to time B. which can be very very huge (billions of data)